# Skid Steer hit exterior wall.... interior wall now bowed

Tags: drywall, framing, foundation, structural, studs

we are buying a new build, and noticed one of the exterior walls (load bearing) is bowed on the interior of the home. We inspected the outside, and it appears (likely during the yard grading) a skid steer has hit the exterior wall pretty significantly, causing bowing to the interior wall (below a window), and cracking in the stucco on the exterior.

We are concerned for the structural integrity of the home, and are worried studs have been knocked off the baseplate and/or top plate. This is a two story home and there is a window at the site of damage.

What steps do we need to take to get this fixed properly? Structural engineer? Does the entire wall have to be opened up and redone? Are we looking any any larger problems or long term damage/issues down the road?

Comment: New build, structural engineer to check and builder to repair to engineer's specs.

Comment: Grounds for walking out of the contract based on substandard workmanship if they are not already in the processes of repairing this on the skid-steer company's insurance. Which they have no incentive to do (other than you not walking)  if they are the skid-steer company as well as the folks pawning off a pre-damaged house on you the buyer.

Comment: what does buying a new build mean?  The house was just built and you are buying it from the builder and will be first owner?    Does it come with a builder warranty or a home warranty?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a legal question about a contract to buy a new house, not a [diy.se] question. At a minimum, the OP needs to be there when the building inspector makes his next visit to ensure that the inspector sees this damage, as he shouldn't sign off until it's repaired by the builder. Who pays for the repairs is the builder's problem, not the buyer's problem.

Comment: How far is it bowed out of position? Are the upper joists resting on the wall or running parallel to the bowed wall? What is the composition of the way (is there plywood on it)? Where do you live (high area or seismic active area ?)

Answer (score 1):

Tear open the inside wall that is bowing and repair as required, then repair the exterior as required. The sheathing may be damaged which would require an extensive exterior repair.  Cracked Stucco or EIFS must must must be repaired by qualified workers.

This should be standard framing, no need for an engineer unless you're planning on not getting it fixed.

And yes, like the comment says, unless you're your own GC, your builder should do this for you.

Comment: A new build is the builders responsibility.  If a builder lets a skid steer or something bang into a house and leaves it, I would want someone to check their work.